# How to find the biggest number in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I find the biggest number from the numbers I've entered in array?

things i've tried already:

```
var largest = Math.max.apply(Math, number[i]);
var smallest = Math.min.apply(Math, number[i]);
```

Comment: You want to find the min/max of the whole array. number[i] would be just one number from the array. (i doesn't exist in this context either) The line should be `Math.max.apply(Math, number);`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're very close:

```
Math.max.apply(Math, number);
```

You need to pass all of the elements of the array to the `max()` metho; `[i]` doesn't make sense here.

Comment: How do you do this if you have a 2D array? I only want to get the max number from the second column in my 2D array which is like this: myArray[[1,25][2,32][3,30]]. I just want to be able to get the 32.

Comment: @SubjectiveEffect: You need to flatten it first (eg, with `concat.apply`)

Answer (score 3):

Math.max.apply is an option like said in other answers, but I think reduce is more common among languages:

```
var number=[1,2,3,2,1,1]; 
number.reduce(function(a,b){return a>b ? a : b;});
// returns 3
Math.max.apply(Math.max, number);
// returns 3
```

Comment: also think reduce is more appropriate for any case.

Answer (score 2):

```
var max = number[0], i = 0;


for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
  if (number[i] > max) {
    max = number[i];
  }
}
```

or I recommend [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#max)

```
var max = _.max(number);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're close, try this:

```
Math.max.apply(Math.max, number);
```

Ie, the second argument converts an array to the list of arguments.

(Actually since *Math.max* never needs *this*, you don't need the first argument of *apply*; so `Math.max.apply(null, number)` or `Math.max.apply('aaaaahhh', number)` works too.)

Answer (score 1):

Using - `Array.prototype.reduce()` is cool!

`[267, 306, 108].reduce((acc,val)=> (acc>val)?acc:val)`

where **acc = accumulator** and **val = current value**;

Answer (score 0):

```
function compare(a, b) {

  if (a > b) return 1
  else if (a < b) return -1
  else return 0
}

var arr = [ 1, 2, 15, 12.5, 16, 3.35 ]

arr.sort(compare)

alert( arr[2] ) // your n number


// i used sort() but because by default it sorting in lexicographical order i 
passed it throuth custom comparisom , it works fine for me
```